# Runtime error: ClassNotFound exception

Tags: android, android-intent, classnotfoundexception, inflate-exception

I've been having this runtime error for almost a week and can't find the solution (I'm a new android programmer). Please help me!

The log is at the end of this message. I know there are some similar questions to mine but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

I'm trying to call a class from activity using `Intent` but the runtime error says that this class couldn't be found.

This is the log file:

```
07-01 13:22:57.098: E/dalvikvm(1488): Could not find class 'com.XXX.ui.ViewPager',
referenced from method com.XXX.ui.MainIWrapper.onCreate
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
    activity ComponentInfo{com.XXX/com.XXX.ui.MainIWrapper}:

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class
com.XXX.ui.NavigationBar
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
Method)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:
Binary
XML file line #43: Error inflating class com.XXX.ui.NavigationBar
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:581)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at  
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
com.XXX.ui.MainIWrapper.onCreate(MainIWrapper.java:69)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     ... 11 more
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
com.XXX.ui.NavigationBar in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.XXX-
2.apk]
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:471)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     at
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
07-01 13:22:57.338: E/AndroidRuntime(1488):     ... 23 more
```

This is the function that deals with the intent:

```
private Activity from;
private Class to;

public void open() {
    Intent intent;
    intent = new Intent(from, to);

    if (extras != null) {
        intent.putExtras(extras);
    }

    if (to.equals(MainWrapper.class)) {
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }

    if (activityForResultRequestCode == -1) {
        from.startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        from.startActivityForResult(intent, activityForResultRequestCode);
    }

    if (pendingAnimation != null && pendingAnimation.length == 2) {
        from.overridePendingTransition(pendingAnimation[0], pendingAnimation[1]);
    } else {
        from.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.hold);
    }

    if (toClosePreviousActivity) {
        from.finish();
    }   
}
```

This is the call **from** the activity (that needs to be changed), with the class I want to load (it uses the `open()` function that is doing the intent):

`UiUtils.getOpenActivityBuilder(SplashScreen.this,MainIWrapper.class).toClosePrev(true).open;`

This is a part of my manifest -- it's the main activity that needs to be changed to the class `MainIWrapper`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.SplashScreen"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

This is the mainWrapper declaration in the manifest file:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.MainIWrapper"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

This is the `mainWrapper` declaration:

```
public class MainIWrapper extends BaseWebSiteScreen implements HasBox {...}
```

And this is the main activity declaration:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {...}
```

---

Thank you for the help But i still can't find the problem(I'm really a beginner in android)

Those are the lines from my XML(from line 43):

```
<com.XXX.ui.NavigationBar
        xmlns:vwpgind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.XXX"
        android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        vwpgind:arrowImageSrc="@drawable/common_slider_arrow"
        vwpgind:hideFirstItem="true" />
```

the code from MainIWrapper.OnCreate() is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_iwrapper);

isUserLoggedIn = UserDetails.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isUserLoggedIn();

//we want to refresh user thumb each time user opens Main iWrapper
if (UserDetails.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isUserLoggedIn())
UserDetails.deleteCachedUserThumb(getApplicationContext());

textBox = (TextBox) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

pageViewAdapter = new PageViewAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(pageViewAdapter);

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUMBER_OF_PAGES_TO_PRELOAD);

navigationBar = (NavigationBar) findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar);
topBar = (TopBar) findViewById(R.id.top_bar);
progressAnimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_animation);
bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);

}
```

I still can't find the error here. I looked at the build path and the src folder with the com.XXX.ui package in it(this package contains the NavigationBar and the ViewPager classes)

---

Those are the lines from my XML(from line 43):

```
 <com.XXX.ui.NavigationBar
            xmlns:vwpgind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.XXX"
            android:id="@+id/navigation_bar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            vwpgind:arrowImageSrc="@drawable/common_slider_arrow"
            vwpgind:hideFirstItem="true" />
```

the code from MainIWrapper.OnCreate() is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_iwrapper);

isUserLoggedIn = UserDetails.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isUserLoggedIn();

//we want to refresh user thumb each time user opens Main iWrapper
if (UserDetails.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).isUserLoggedIn())
    UserDetails.deleteCachedUserThumb(getApplicationContext());

textBox = (TextBox) findViewById(R.id.text_box);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

pageViewAdapter = new PageViewAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(pageViewAdapter);

viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NUMBER_OF_PAGES_TO_PRELOAD);

navigationBar = (NavigationBar) findViewById(R.id.navigation_bar);
topBar = (TopBar) findViewById(R.id.top_bar);
progressAnimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress_animation);
bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottom_bar);

}
```

I still can't see what is the problem here

```
public class ViewPager extends android.support.v4.view.ViewPager {

public ViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
    try {
        return super.onSaveInstanceState();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't check whether the classes referenced in the layout XML files exists, so it is normal to only get the error at runtime.

Most likely the com.`XXX.ui.NavigationBar` class doesn't exist on your classpath. Check your package names, maybe it's just a typo, or maybe you forgot to change the package names in the XML file after a package name refactor on the `NavigationBar` class.

Answer (score 0):

Errors are all here:

`07-01 13:22:57.098: E/dalvikvm(1488): Could not find class 'com.XXX.ui.ViewPager',
referenced from method com.XXX.ui.MainIWrapper.onCreate
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class
com.XXX.ui.NavigationBar`

Post the code from your MainIWrapper.onCreate() and have a look at line 43 in your XML for NavigationBar.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for the help
But i still can't find the problem(I'm really a beginner in android)

This is the lines from my XML(from line 43):

Comment: I did posted it in my question above

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are doing with the xmlns: and the vwpgnd: tags in the XML definition of NavigationBar. What are you trying to do here? Do you have a class called com.XXX.ui.ViewPager? Post the code for ViewPager.

Comment: Yes I have. I'm adding it's code to the question.
I'll explain what I'm trying to do:
in the function open() above I'm trying to create intent that start the "to" class from the "from" activity. The "from" activity is my SplashScreen activity and the "to" class is the mainIWrapper class.
That's how far i can tell by the debugger because then some thread is trying to load the class mainIWrapper or one of the XMLs ViewPager or NavigationBar and it fails. I hope that it was clear
I'm adding the code of ViewWrapper to the question and thanks again

Comment: Have you put the v4-comatibility library into your /libs directory? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780413/error-inflating-class-android-support-v4-view-viewpager