# Inflating android.support.v4.ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

Although I have tried current solutions in stackoverflow [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9831019/updated-sdk-version-getting-classnotfoundexception-android-support-v4-view-vie) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614337/android-viewpager-xml-inflate-error), I still cannot solve inflating ViewPager error. I am using UniversalImageLoader library and I think I have referenced the latest version of android.support.v4 library in right way. Here you can see my code and settings:

Image Pager class

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_pager); //Here it returns the error below

    ...
```

ac_image_pager layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager  <!--Error shows this line-->
        android:id="@+id/pager"
       android:layout_above="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat

```
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969): Process: com.example.mobilyol.most, PID: 20969
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.imageapp.ScaleImageView
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at com.example.mobilyol.most.ImagePagerActivity$ImagePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ImagePagerActivity.java:88)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:837)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:987)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5137)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16540)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1942)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1132)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1321)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1019)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5725)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.imageapp.ScaleImageView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.mobilyol.most-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.mobilyol.most-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
07-11 14:03:05.723: E/AndroidRuntime(20969):    ... 40 more
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the class `com.example.imageapp.ScaleImageView`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your exception is:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.example.imageapp.ScaleImageView`

The layout file that you pasted in does not have a `ScaleImageView`. While your problem is being *triggered* by your use of a `ViewPager`, your actual problem is in the *pages* that the `ViewPager` is creating, which presumably involves a different layout file.

Please make sure that you have a class whose fully-qualified name is `com.example.imageapp.ScaleImageView`.

Comment: that was very helpful. I found the mistake in another layout file that I was referencing something I copied from another project.