# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager"?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-fragments

Error in library - android-support-v4.jar
Using library's - Greendroid, facebook sdk, actionbarsherlock
Eclipse - 4.4.0
Android SDK - 23.0.5

I have tried removing the library and adding it again tried using same/separate v4 library for all project also tried cleaning restarting changing workspace checking/unchecking order and export nothing helped

Here is the error log -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AIS.cloudplus/com.rakatech.geodairy.main.PhotoDiaryHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2309)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:157)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1289)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:760)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
 at com.rakatech.geodairy.main.PhotoDiaryHomeActivity.onCreate(PhotoDiaryHomeActivity.java:256)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
 ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" on path: /data/app/com.AIS.cloudplus-4.apk
 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:558)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:693)
 ... 19 more
```

Comment: Did you follow [these](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) instructions? Are you adding the library with resources or without?

Comment: Did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15614337/android-viewpager-xml-inflate-error

Comment: We have tried almost every solution in stackoverflow, well it was previously working good, haven't made any changes just changed the workspace

Comment: delete your project from your workspace and then re-import into your workspace again. Hope it wil work.

Comment: Deleting and re-importing the project doesn't work for me.