# Implementing ViewPager into a LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

What I am trying to do is to have a ViewPager section on my app, where the user can scroll to see the results. I am using Android Studio.

At the moment I am currently displaying the results like so, by outputting the values to *out* by stringing them together:

**Part of Main_Activity.java**

```
class CustomOnItemSelectedListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {
        String tempValue = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        float inputValue;
        if(text.getText().length() == 0) {
             inputValue = Float.parseFloat("10");
             text.setText("10");
        }
        else {
             inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
        }

        if ("Fahrenheit".equals(tempValue)) {
            out.setText(String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)) + " & " + String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertFahrenheitToKelvin(inputValue)));
            type.setText("Celsius + Kelvin");
           }
        if ("Celsius".equals(tempValue)) {
            out.setText(String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)) + " & " + String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertCelsiusToKelvin(inputValue)));
            type.setText("Fahrenheit + Kelvin");
        }
        if ("Kelvin".equals(tempValue)) {
            out.setText(String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertKelvinToCelsius(inputValue)) + " & " + String.valueOf(ConverterUtil.convertKelvinToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
            type.setText("Celsius + Fahrenheit");
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to to have each result in a separate view in which the user can scroll, however this is where I get a little lost/confused.

I have implemented my Fragment:

**Part of Main_Activity.java**

```
class ScreenSlidePagerActivity extends FragmentActivity

{
    private static final int NUM_PAGES = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
}

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the activity_main.xml layout, I have replaced the out & type fields with a ViewPager:

**Part of activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When called, it loads this class and displays the information using my result_slider layout:

**ScreenSlidePageFragment.java**

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.result_slider, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

**result_slider.xml**

```
<com.example.temperatureconverter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView style="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />

</com.example.temperatureconverter>
```

How can I go about passing the data from my results to a pane in the ViewPager?  Using the code below, I don't get any errors, however the app crashes with *Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager*

Comment: Hi, Could you please provide a full log of the crash?

Comment: Hi, log here: http://pastebin.com/kxecYpRg

Comment: Which ViewPager are you using, the one from the support library? What version of android are you building for?

Comment: Yes, the one from the support library (android.support.v4.view.ViewPager) The minimum SDK is 14 and the target is 19

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10781162/1025599

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to show me there.  The Support Library is already included in the buildpath.  It builds fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following the answer to this question: [How to implement a ViewPager with different Fragments / Layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18413309/how-to-implement-a-viewpager-with-different-fragments-layouts)

Make sure you include the libraries and merge your MainActivity with the one from the answer.

Then in your layout file for the MainActivity, put your ViewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />
```

Where you would like the content to scroll/go