# Android app development using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am doing Tabhost + ViewPager + Sliding menu in android using eclipse and error occoured The following classes could not be found: - android.support.v4.view.viewPager (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class) what should i do

Comment: did u add appcompactv7 library?

Comment: I expected a semi opinion based question about eclipse and android studio when I looked at the title. Please put some effort in coming up with a title that reflects your actual question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780413/error-inflating-class-android-support-v4-view-viewpager

Answer (score 0):

this problem comes from your imports
use ctrl + 1 on part of your code that is underlined for error , and click on import . if the error caused by imports , this should fix that.

Comment: *this should fix that.* only if the required library is already linked, which does not seem to be the case

Comment: he is getting errors on android.support.v4 libraris , he is not imported libraries or \libs\android-support-v4.jar is missing from his libs .

Comment: Yes but pressing ctrl+1 won't magically put the support library in your project

Comment: i know !!
usually when you create an app in eclipse or android studio , it include that jar in your project , so ctlr+1 should fix it