# Android Studio project works on Lollipop but does not work on Kitkat

Tags: android, android-viewpager, inflate-exception

I have an Android Studio project that is working fine on devices with Android build version Lollipop but is throwing an exception when trying to run it on a device with android build version Kitkat. This is my project's build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

            renderscriptTargetApi 22
            renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
    compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar')
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.6.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/pinit-sdk-1.0.jar')
    compile project(':bounceScroller')
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.+'
    compile 'com.esri.arcgis.android:arcgis-android:10.2.6-2'
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.3'
    compile 'com.github.pedrovgs:draggablepanel:1.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.2.0'
    compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.2.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    compile project(':rangeseekbar')
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    compile project(':blurry')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
}
```

and here is the error I am getting when I run the application on a Kitkat device:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2010)
            at android.visitabudhabi.com.vad.Walkthrough.onCreate(Walkthrough.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2010)
            at android.visitabudhabi.com.vad.Walkthrough.onCreate(Walkthrough.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompatFroyo
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat$FroyoViewConfigurationVersionImpl.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(ViewConfigurationCompat.java:56)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewConfigurationCompat.getScaledPagingTouchSlop(ViewConfigurationCompat.java:105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.initViewPager(ViewPager.java:368)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.<init>(ViewPager.java:356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2010)
            at android.visitabudhabi.com.vad.Walkthrough.onCreate(Walkthrough.java:32)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my XML that has the ViewPager:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.3"
            android:background="#c7333f" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/second"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.3"
            android:background="#FFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/third"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3.3"
            android:background="#fff" />
    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Comment: please add your layout thats there is viewpager

Comment: @HosseinGerami I will update my question immediately.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780413/error-inflating-class-android-support-v4-view-viewpager

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya all my libraries are installed in the project using Gradle.

Comment: @Lefteris no actually I am building for API 21, see the default config in my build.gradle that i posted in the question.

Comment: can you update your styles.xml & v-21/styles.xml. Might be a problem with theme like `NoActionBar`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is how I solved the problem if anyone gets here.

After I searched deeply about the problem, I found out that it's not an inflating exception though that's what the logcat said, the real exception was OutOfMemory exception caused by the infamous 65K problem [click here for more information about the problem](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html) and it was wrapped with the inflate excpetion.

To solve the problem, I firstly added the multidex support library in my build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Then I followed these three simple steps to make it work:

1. If you’re not implementing an Application class yourself, you can simply define the library’s MultiDexApplication in your Android Manifest file under the application tag:

   android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
2. If you are implementing your own Application class, you can either simply override the MultiDexApplication file:

   public class MyAwesomeApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
3. Or if your application class is already extending another class, you can just override attachBaseContext method and add the following call to it:

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
   super.attachBaseContext(context);
   Multidex.install(this);
   }

I already had my own application class that extends from class "Application" so I jumped directly to step 3 and voila it worked on Kitkat and on Lollipop.

Hope this helps anyone. Happy Coding.

Comment: Glad to see that .Nice explanations .Happy coding

Comment: it is not working for me.
I have set minSdkVersion 17 targetSdkVersion 26
renderScriptTargetApi 19

this is happening after I have integrated Realm Database.

Please suggest me a solution.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: your answer is so weird, if you create your app class of course it will be extending `Application` so point 2 will never work, and what happend with context in point 3: `@Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { super.attachBaseContext(context); Multidex.install(this); }` you have `base` variable but then you're trying to use no existing `context` and just `this`, so weird

Comment: @user924 Wow, so you're a smart one eh? What I meant by point 2 is that if you didn't create an application class before, you can create one and extend MultiDexApplication instead of Application, and you can leave it empty if you don't need it in any other feature. In point 3 the variable base references to the same object as the word this so using either one is the same but somehow depending on your great experience you found that so weird. so thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: @EyadMhanna of course it's weird when you use three different variables to the same object in one or two code lines, why not just using `this` three times? does who even write such code?

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your compileSdkVersion does not match major version of support libraries you include with the project. Follow these rules:

Set targetSdkVersion to 22 because you want to use Lollipop features on Lollipop devices (and don't care about Marshmallow for now).

Set compileSdkVersion to 23 because it's the newest.

Set buildToolsVersion to "23.0.1" because it's the newest.

Set support library versions to the latest matching compileSdkVersion:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay . At first call `fill_parent` .

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

And use this instead of yours .

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
```

set `targetSdkVersion 19`

**Edit1**

you set

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and

```
targetSdkVersion 23
```

I hope it will helps you .

Comment: for testing case set `minSdkVersion 15`

Comment: @Eyadoos I am not sure .Try this and give feedback

Comment: I don't if this will work or not, but even if it did i can't use this solution because many desing functionalities in the application require API 21