# Set foreground to imageview

Tags: android, shapes, selecteditem, foreground

I set foreground to my imageview to select when it has been selected. This works fine in android 6 version. On select nothing changes in min versions. Please help me.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/style_list_item_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:foreground="@drawable/style_item_selector"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:clipChildren="true"
        android:clipToPadding="true"/>
```

style_item_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <size android:width="60dp" android:height="80dp" />
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff3591" />
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent100" />
            <corners android:radius="1dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a solution for you

**Selector would be like this**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <size android:width="60dp" android:height="80dp" />
        <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff3591" />
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <corners android:radius="1dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

ImageView need some wrap up

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:foreground="@drawable/style_item_selector">


    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/style_list_item_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:clipChildren="true"
    android:clipToPadding="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this works for you!

**Make sure you attach onClickListener to the FrameLayout**

Answer (score 2):

```
        case R.styleable.View_foreground:
            if (targetSdkVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M || this instanceof FrameLayout) {
                setForeground(a.getDrawable(attr));
            }
            break;
```

This is the code inside View.java initialization. foreground works only for API-23+ and for FrameLayout

Answer (score -7):

Add this code in `build.gradle file`   and rebuild

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

I hope this will help you. GL :)
Found from [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33327442/android-studio-project-works-on-lollipop-but-does-not-work-on-kitkat)