# Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.view.ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-widget, android-support-library

hello guy I would like to create a Tab Layout & View Pager in android studio
here is my activity_xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
      app:tabGravity="fill"
      app:tabMode="fixed"
      app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
      android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager_id">
    </android.support.v4.widget.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my MainActivity :

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout_id);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager_id);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentCall(),"Call"); // `new FragmentCall()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentContact(), "Contact"); // `new FragmentContact()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`
        viewPagerAdapter.AddFragment(new FragmentFav(), "Fav"); // `new FragmentFav()` should be inside `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()`

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }
}
```

the error say : Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.v4.widget.view.ViewPager
and : Didn't find class "android.support.v4.widget.view.ViewPager
I've ever to search this error in this link : [Error inflating class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780413/error-inflating-class-android-support-v4-view-viewpager), but I do not understand how to resolve the error, he say Right click on the jar, then select Build Path and click on Add to Build Path. And I do not understand how to select Build Path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
android.support.v4.widget.view.ViewPager
```

with

```
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

Comment: I was adding that & I sync but its nothing change